# How to change Picker underline color in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, picker

I am using `Picker` control, by default it shows White underline color on Black screen.

[image]

But I need to have white screen background color, then `Picker` underline is not displaying at all. See below image:

[image]

So how can I change `Picker` underline color

This is my `Picker`

```
 <Picker TitleColor="Black" Title="--Select--" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use custom renderer to achieve it：

for Android:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Picker), typeof(CustomPickerRenderer))]
namespace App18.Droid
{
  public class CustomPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
   {
      private Context context;
      public CustomPickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
       {
        this.context = context;
       }

      protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
       {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control == null || e.NewElement == null) return;
        //for example ,change the line to red:
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
            Control.BackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Color.Red);
        else
            Control.Background.SetColorFilter(Color.Red, PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
       }
   }
}
```

for iOS:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Picker), typeof(CustomPickerRenderer))]
namespace App18.iOS
{
  public class CustomPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
   {

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null || e.NewElement == null)
            return; 
        Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
        Control.Layer.BorderColor = Color.Red.ToCGColor();
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: If I use rednderer, then I need it for both iOS and Android.

Comment: @Arvindraja i have updated the answer,you could try to run it

Comment: Don't we have anything except `BorderColor` in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <app1:DatePickerNoLine x:Name="datePickerScheduleDate"    Unfocused="ScheduleCriteriaChanged" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" FontSize="Subtitle" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
                                <BoxView x:Name="BoxdatePickerScheduleDate" HeightRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"   Color="Black" WidthRequest="{Binding WidthRequest, Source={x:Reference datePickerScheduleDate}}" />
                            </StackLayout>

Use the custom renderer to remove the underline that comes with picker.

protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                this.Control.Text = Element.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
               
                Control.Layer.BackgroundColor = Color.White.ToCGColor();

                Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
                Control.Layer.BorderColor = Color.Transparent.ToCGColor();

                Control.LeftView = new UIKit.UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, 10, 0));
                Control.LeftViewMode = UIKit.UITextFieldViewMode.Always;


                UITextField entry = Control;
                UIDatePicker picker = (UIDatePicker)entry.InputView;
                picker.PreferredDatePickerStyle = UIDatePickerStyle.Wheels;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Solution by "Leo Zhu - MSFT" sets the border color, all 4 sides of it.  Question was how to change the underline color.