# How to change the background color of a Xamarin Forms picker GUI?

Tags: forms, user-interface, xamarin, element, picker

I want to preface this by saying most threads I've researched show how to change the background color of the picker element itself, NOT the GUI.

The White Android GUI is really off-putting and doesn't match the rest of my application, I want to change the title and color of the background. How do I achieve this? Also, if possible, how do I change the dimensions of this element?

[The GUI I am trying to change.]
[image]

I have tried creating a CustomPickerRenderer and changing the background color, however this changes the background of the element before being clicked. This is not what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: You can't change this, the only way is to write your own custom control!

Comment: You need to use the custom rander to change the GUI of the Picker in Xamarin. Here is the code about [how to use the custom render to change the picker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56014932/19335715) you can refer to.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably have noticed there is no properties on the Picker control that allow you to change the appearance of the popup that's displayed when the Picker is opened.

As far of writing your own custom Picker control that has a "PopupBackgroundColor" property, this route is probably not going to be very fruitful or create a bunch of extra work to make your app have a consistent appearance.

On Android Xamarin uses Android's `AlertDialog`. Unfortunately there isn't a way to customize the background through this class or the `AlertDialob.Builder`. However on Android there is away to [customize the appearance of the AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog) for your whole app using themes. This is probably the preferred method in Android since it will make all picker dialogs consistent. Note this will also change the appearance of other popups in your app. Which is probably more of a feature than a bug.

On iOS Xamarin uses `UIAlertController` as well there is no way to set background color on the Popup. I'm less familiar with theming on iOS but it appears you only have two options a light (white background) or dark (black background) theme.

So take a look at the Native platform theme settings and see if that aligns with how you setup the appearance of your app. If you want to handle both light and dark themes take a look at the [ApplicationThemeBinging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/system-theme-changes) markup extension to handle both light and dark themes.